# MLP = Sin(x1-x2+x3-x4)

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, perceptron

i have this function to update the weights for my mlp  for  the sin function

it works for the xor   no problem but  i cant figure  out  why  it wont  for my sin there  both  called the same way  but i keep getting

the  error :

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

```py
def update_weights(self, learning_rate):

    self.weights1 = np.add(self.weights1, learning_rate * self.delta_weights1)
    self.weights2 = np.add(self.weights2, learning_rate * self.delta_weights2)
    self.delta_weights1 = np.array
    self.delta_weights2 = np.array
```

Can anyone  point  me in the  right  direction  with  this ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from these lines:

```
self.delta_weights1 = np.array
self.delta_weights2 = np.array
```

`self.delta_weights1` will be assigned the function (or function pointer) `np.array` without calling it.

If you do for example:

```
type(np.array)
```

you'll get:

```
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

while if you call the function (i.e. add parentheses), which requires an object to transform into an array:

```
type(np.array([]))
```

you'll get:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

---

If you want to reset the `delta_weights` variables to zero after doing the weights update (e.g. before accumulating the contributions from the next minibatch), use something like:

```py
self.delta_weights1 = np.zeros(self.weights1.shape)
self.delta_weights2 = np.zeros(self.weights2.shape)
```

(see also the [np.zeros()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) documentation).